# ReportViewer: In Net4.0 should not throw an exception for requiring a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, migration, .net-2.0, reporting

i'm migrating an ASP.NET web application from .NET 2 to .NET 4.0 and have a problem about the reporting side.

The thing is whenever i try to call a report (via webservice reportServer), i have this exception :
**The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form**

From what i understood of this Exception is that i had to add scriptManager tag in the .aspx , which i did. The exception currently doesnt occur, but the report is now completly blank.

Do you guys have experienced the same thing and had anyone figure it out ?

Thank you

Comment: facing similar issue. did you find any solution to this

Comment: Im sorry its been 2 years i didnt do .net

Comment: Cool. No problem